# I need to transfer data from GPS module to char[ ] in Arduino IDE. The question is what is ( / 10 + 48; ) or (/ 10) % 10 + 48;) How this used for?

Tags: c++, string, arduino, char, gps

Please, name thise methods.I new there, could you provide some reference?

```
        char Time[]  = "TIME:00:00:00";
        void loop() {
        Date[5]  = gps.date.day()    / 10 + 48;
        Date[6]  = gps.date.day()    % 10 + 48;         
        Date[8]  = gps.date.month()  / 10 + 48;  //Please, name thise methods.
        Date[9]  = gps.date.month()  % 10 + 48;
        Date[13] =(gps.date.year()   / 10) % 10 + 48;
        Date[14] = gps.date.year()   % 10 + 48;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding 48 is a way to convert a digit to a corresponding character. ASCII codes of digits start with 48 for '0'. so `5 + '0'` is '5'.

`x / 10` is division of x by 10. with integer division you get 2 from 23

`x % 10` is modulo of x by 10. you get the remainder of division of x by 10. so you get 3 from 23.

So the code in question converts time digit by digit to a printable text.